# How to tar my C++ files on a linux server?

Tags: tar

I know this is a simple question, but I'm not sure why the tar process isn't working and I can't find a definitive answer on here. When doing the tar command:

```
tar -cvjf<assign2comp.tar.bz2> <assign2.cpp header.cpp header.h>
```

I'm getting the error, **Missing name for redirect**. 
Our professor shows this code as the example so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
tar -cvjf<filename.tar.bz2> <files you want in archive>
```

Then to extract:

```
tar -jxvf filename.tar.bz2
```

So I want to archive the assign2.cpp header.cpp and header.h files then test the extract command to make sure I can access them.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you actually type in the less than/greater than signs? `<` or `>`?  Those are typically used to denote placeholder values.

Comment: Yeah, I know that was really dumb. I've seen them many times before but I'm pretty new to the Linux server stuff so I just wasn't sure. Stupid mistake.

Comment: As a side-note: be careful with `>` in the shell: this causes the output to be written to the file that immediately follows `>`, so you can accidentally overwrite files if not careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drop the < and > characters from commands. e.g. tar -cvjf assign2comp.tar.bz2 assign2.cpp header.cpp header.h

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll mark as answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

When you were told to use `<file>` it means to write your filename there, without `<` and `>`.  So:

```
tar -cvjf assign2comp.tar.bz2 assign2.cpp header.cpp header.h
```

This is a common convention on Unix: `<file>` means a filename is required, `[host]` means a host is optional, and so on.